# What is the difference between Dark Souls on Steam and Games for Windows Live?

Tags: dark-souls, version-differences

What is the difference between Steam and Games for Windows Live versions of *Dark Souls*? I'm not sure, but I read somewhere that Steam version is also connected with GFWL.

I'm asking because my friend is going to buy it, but I'm not sure if the Steam version is able to play with GFWL.

Comment: Don't forget to make sure you have an XBox 360 controller for your PC before you buy it.  The keyboard controls are rubbish and other controllers not necessarily that good with the game.  Still an awesome game though.

Comment: You can use a PS3 Controller as well you just need to download and use DS3_Tool, which is another question entirely if you don't know how.

Comment: I play with keyboard and I don't have too much problems, beside  targeting is terrible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'Steam version' is just the GFWL version made for sale via steam. You still have to login to a GFWL account to play online.

Comment: However the steam version allows for the steam background UI so you can browse the web, get steam chat in game etc so theres that.

Comment: So steam version is only digital version right ? Is it possible to add box version to steam ?

Comment: @user1165499 No it is not, you can add it as a shortcut in steam to get use of the steam overlay, but you can not add the actual game to your account.

Comment: @Shykin: Each of the features you've mentioned can also be gotten via the 'Add non-Steam game to Library' option.

Comment: @ChristopherBerman I've had hit and miss with that method but in this case it would probably work.